# How to find all next elements Until one or two elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this selector in jquery

```
$(ptr).nextUntil('tr.item').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
```

But I want to do something like this

```
$(ptr).nextUntil('tr.item' OR 'tr.ptype').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
```

I have already tried this selector, but it does not work as I want:

```
 $(ptr).nextUntil('tr.item, tr.ptype').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Example, there are two cases, it should remove all the tr.add_tr elements until find a coincidence of tr.item or tr.ptype

```
CASE 1



<tr class="item"></tr> <!-- i'm here -->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- remove it -->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr><!-- remove it -->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr><!-- remove it-->
<tr class="ptype"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="item"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->




CASE 2

<tr class="item"></tr> <!-- i'm here -->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- remove it -->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr><!-- remove it -->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr><!-- remove it-->
<tr class="item"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="ptype"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="item"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
<tr class="add_tr"></tr> <!-- don't remove it-->
```

Can you help me please.

Comment: See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/9fzpuwvs/). This is based on Lalji's answer.

Comment: it does not work because it has to stop either it finds a tr.ptype or a tr.item

Comment: Why does $(ptr).nextUntil('tr.item, tr.ptype') not work? I tested it out, and it worked for me.

Comment: fiddle of my example: https://jsfiddle.net/u5fn7cde/

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this :

```
    $(ptr).nextUntil('tr.item, tr.ptype').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you can change add a colon between the elements. Something like this

```
$(ptr).nextUntil('tr.item,tr.ptype').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Let me know if this worked?

Comment: it does not work because it has to stop either it finds a tr.ptype or a tr.item